# Query not recognize alias

Tags: oracle

I have the following query, the alias it's called DELAY, works fine, but when I try to run the first query adding `AND DELAY < 0`, the alias is not recognized.

I tried to create the alias **QUERY AS** **DELAY** or **QUERY AS "DELAY"** but no success.

The strange thing is that the alias DELAY in the order by doesn't generate errors.

```
 SELECT ITK_TCK_ID, 
                   ITK_OPENED_DATE, 
                   TO_NUMBER(ROUND(ROUND(GET_HS(ITK_OPENED_DATE, 
                                                SYSDATE, 
                                                ITK_NORMAL_BEGIN, 
                                                ITK_NORMAL_END, 
                                                ITK_WEEKEND_BEGIN, 
                                                ITK_WEEKEND_END, 
                                                ITK_FREEDAY_BEGIN, 
                                                ITK_FREEDAY_END), 
                                         GET_HS(ITK_OPENED_DATE, 
                                                SYSDATE, 
                                                ITK_NORMAL_BEGIN, 
                                                ITK_NORMAL_END, 
                                                ITK_WEEKEND_BEGIN, 
                                                ITK_WEEKEND_END, 
                                                ITK_FREEDAY_BEGIN, 
                                                ITK_FREEDAY_END)) - 
                                   ITK_EXPIRATION_TIME, 
                                   2)) DELAY 
              FROM INSTANTIATED_TICKLERS 
             WHERE ITK_AR_SBP_ID = 'PEAJU_PP' -- P_WGR_ID 
             AND DELAY < 0 
             ORDER BY DELAY DESC;
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use column aliases in the WHERE clause at the same level where the alias was defined.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10592/statements_10002.htm#SQLRF55280

**c_alias**

> Specify an alias for the column expression. Oracle Database will use
>   this alias in the column heading of the result set. The AS keyword is
>   optional. The alias effectively renames the select list item for the
>   duration of the query. **The alias can be used in the order_by_clause
>   but not other clauses in the query.**

Use an inline view:

```
 SELECT * FROM (
     SELECT ITK_TCK_ID, 
                       ITK_OPENED_DATE, 
                       TO_NUMBER(ROUND(ROUND(GET_HS(ITK_OPENED_DATE, 
                                                    SYSDATE, 
                                                    ITK_NORMAL_BEGIN, 
                                                    ITK_NORMAL_END, 
                                                    ITK_WEEKEND_BEGIN, 
                                                    ITK_WEEKEND_END, 
                                                    ITK_FREEDAY_BEGIN, 
                                                    ITK_FREEDAY_END), 
                                             GET_HS(ITK_OPENED_DATE, 
                                                    SYSDATE, 
                                                    ITK_NORMAL_BEGIN, 
                                                    ITK_NORMAL_END, 
                                                    ITK_WEEKEND_BEGIN, 
                                                    ITK_WEEKEND_END, 
                                                    ITK_FREEDAY_BEGIN, 
                                                    ITK_FREEDAY_END)) - 
                                       ITK_EXPIRATION_TIME, 
                                       2)) DELAY 
                  FROM INSTANTIATED_TICKLERS 
                 WHERE ITK_AR_SBP_ID = 'PEAJU_PP' -- P_WGR_ID 
  )          
  WHERE DELAY < 0 
  ORDER BY DELAY DESC;
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because the WHERE executes before the SELECT. You could try calculating  DELAY inside the WHERE

```
WHERE ITK_AR_SBP_ID = 'PEAJU_PP' -- P_WGR_ID 
AND TO_NUMBER(ROUND(ROUND(GET_HS(ITK_OPENED_DATE, 
             SYSDATE, 
             ITK_NORMAL_BEGIN, 
             ITK_NORMAL_END, 
             ITK_WEEKEND_BEGIN, 
             ITK_WEEKEND_END, 
             ITK_FREEDAY_BEGIN, 
             ITK_FREEDAY_END), 
        GET_HS(ITK_OPENED_DATE, 
             SYSDATE, 
             ITK_NORMAL_BEGIN, 
             ITK_NORMAL_END, 
             ITK_WEEKEND_BEGIN, 
             ITK_WEEKEND_END, 
             ITK_FREEDAY_BEGIN, 
             ITK_FREEDAY_END)) - 
        ITK_EXPIRATION_TIME, 
      2) < 0
```

Comment: Thats the thing that i try to avoid....